# What's wrong withe following code? I get a segmentation error

Tags: c

When I tried to execute the following code it was showing as a segmentation error after I input 2 numbers.. I didn't find any errors.. This is a program for reading n numbers from user and adding all the digits of all the numbers and printing it.

```
/*Read n numbers and find sum of digits*/

#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n, num[50], sum=0, dig, i;
    printf("\nHow many number you want to enter: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\nEnter numbers: ");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", num[i]); //Enter each number inputted from keyboard
        printf("\nThe number entered now  %d", num[i]);
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        while(num[i] != 0)
        {
            dig = num[i]%10; //finding out the digits of each number
            sum = sum + dig;
            num[i] = num[i]/10;
            printf("\nSm of digits till now: ", sum);
        }
    }
    printf("\nSum of digits of all numbers entered: %d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You forgot `&` operator in scanf:

```
scanf("%d", num[i]);
```

Should be:

```
scanf("%d", &num[i]); 
 //         ^^
```

Btw, learn [Indenting C Programs](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~mccann/indent_c.html) correctly.

> I didn't find any errors

Yes your program compiles but your should not ignore warnings. For example in your code with gcc warning is as follows that describes the problem .

> warning: format `‘%d’` expects argument of type `‘int *’`, but argument 2 has type `‘int’`
>     [-Wformat]

It says argument second in scanf function call that is `num[i]` is of int type (becuase declaration of `num` as int array) while according to first argument `%d` it should be of `int*`, means you need to pass address this implies you forgot `&` address of operator `&` ampersand.

Comment: That's correct. However, his identing if fine, that's really a matter of style - no need for religious wars on the matter!

Comment: Thank you, Grijesh Chauhan, very much! yes problem resolved now. ANd thanks for the indentation suggestions. Will try to practice them well.